# How do I retrieve an artifact checksum from Nexus using their rest api via curl?

Tags: rest, curl, deployment, automation, nexus

I am trying to verify the checksum of the artifacts I am downloading from Nexus. I can grab the artifact and download them and check their md5sum or sha1sum, but I need to check this against the actual sum from Nexus so I can verify they are correct.

This is the command I'm using to grab files from Nexus:

```
curl -v -L -o /mylocation/artifact.war -u 'myuser:mypass' --get 'http://ournexus.com/service/local/artifact/maven/content?g=com.ours.stuff&a=our-service-war&v=LATEST&r=snapshots&p=war'
```

Via http://nexus.xwiki.org/nexus/nexus-indexer-lucene-plugin/default/docs/path__lucene_search.html, it would appear that I can also search for the sha1 sum, but when I do &sha1 I get nothing extra or sha1=(sum), nothing is pulled up, even if I omit all the above options.

This works, but it goes to a specific war, and we need the latest (obviously):

```
http://ournexus.com/service/local/repositories/snapshots/content/com/ours/stuff/ourapp/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ourapp-1.0.0-20140730.173704-88.war.sha1
```

Is this possible, am I on the right track?

Comment: For non maven repos, append `?describe=info` to the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345939/nexus-2-get-checksum-of-file-in-raw-repository/36345940#36345940

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either fetch the file directly or use the Nexus API to retrieve it programmatically.

The following URL:

```
http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/resolve?g=log4j&a=log4j&v=1.2.9&r=central
```

Returns the following result:

```
<artifact-resolution>
  <data>
    <presentLocally>true</presentLocally>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9</version>
    <extension>jar</extension>
    <snapshot>false</snapshot>
    <snapshotBuildNumber>0</snapshotBuildNumber>
    <snapshotTimeStamp>0</snapshotTimeStamp>
    <sha1>55856d711ab8b88f8c7b04fd85ff1643ffbfde7c</sha1>
    <repositoryPath>/log4j/log4j/1.2.9/log4j-1.2.9.jar</repositoryPath>
  </data>
</artifact-resolution>
```

The xmllint command can be used to parse out the sha1 checksum value as follows:

```
$ curl -s "http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/resolve?g=log4j&a=log4j&v=1.2.9&r=central" | xmllint --xpath "///sha1/text()" -
55856d711ab8b88f8c7b04fd85ff1643ffbfde7c
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was able to parse out the sum of the latest war that we needed. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 6):

**Nexus 2**

Use the [artifact content API](https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/path__artifact_maven_content.html) to directly get the MD5/SHA1 checksum file by specifying the `p` (packaging) or `e` (extension) parameter as `jar.md5` or `jar.sha1` (or other relevant for your actual packaging).

Example:

```
$ curl -s 'http://mynexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content?g=com.example&a=example&v=1.2.3&r=my-repo&e=jar.sha1'
55856d711ab8b88f8c7b04fd85ff1643ffbfde7c
```

**Nexus 3**

Use the [Search API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api#SearchAPI-SearchandDownloadAsset) to find and download the asset.

```
$ curl -sL 'https://mynexus/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?repository=my-repo&sort=version&maven.groupId=com.example&maven.artifactId=example&maven.baseVersion=LATEST-SNAPSHOT&maven.extension=jar.sha1&maven.classifier='
7ff1ca9fb889c73d095b69a52d5c8609482b63ab
```

Comment: Note: I've found that for a for an ear file this will be ear.sha1. I imagine for a war file it'll be war.sha1.

Answer (score 3):

The query below works for me

```
curl -u USER:PASS -X GET 'https://nexus.example.com:8443/service/rest/v1/search?repository=REPO_NAME&name=FILE_NAME' | jq '.items[0].assets[0].checksum'
```

Always good to check the API [doc](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api).

ps: username and password might be not needed for GET