# How to get artifacts SHA1 using mvn command

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I am using maven to download jar when deploying. I would like to check the checksum of a deployed jar to prevent redeploy of the same version.

Downloading full jar can be made with this command:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DgroupId=com.c.abcd -DartifactId=javaRocket -Dversion=$jar_version -Dpackaging=jar -Dclassifier=shaded -DremoteRepositories=http://repo:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/ -Ddest=C:\\Windows\\temp\\javaRocket.jar -Dtransitive=false
```

Is it possible to download  the SHA1 by similar command or some metadata, where is the SHA1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deploying, Maven prints the URLs it uses. If it tells you that it deploys `http://.../org/some/artifact/1.0/artifact-1.0.jar`, then you should be able to get the SHA1 checksum by downloading `http://.../org/some/artifact/1.0/artifact-1.0.jar.sha1` with a web browser or a command line tool like `wget` or `curl`. I don't know a Maven command or plugin to download only the checksum.

Maven itself ignores the checksum when it comes to double deployment/download; it only uses the release version (i.e. a version without `-SNAPSHOT`).

Comment: I need to specify the version dynamically, there is a possibility to work with SNAPSHOT. I am considering using nexus API to get the SHA from there.

Comment: have you considered scripting?

Comment: Using approach from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047781/how-do-i-retrieve-an-artifact-checksum-from-nexus-using-their-rest-api-via-curl