# nexus 2 get checksum of file in "raw" repository

Tags: nexus

Using sonatype nexus 2.x, how do you get the sha1 or md5 hash of a file in a "site repository" (called "raw repositories" in nexus 3) using curl?

[There is a related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047781/how-do-i-retrieve-an-artifact-checksum-from-nexus-using-their-rest-api-via-curl), however it only applies to "maven" repositories, which has a different api endpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Take the download link and append `?describe=info`

```
curl -H "Accept:application/json" \
"http://nexus.example.com/nexus/service/local/repositories/foobar/content/master-5678.zip?describe=info"
```

The optional `-H "Accept:application/json"` curl flag returns json instead of xml

```
{
   "data":{
      "presentLocally":true,
      "repositoryId":"foobar",
      "repositoryName":"foobar",
      "repositoryPath":"/master-5678.zip",
      "mimeType":"application/zip",
      "uploader":"bob",
      "uploaded":1459458352000,
      "lastChanged":1459458352000,
      "size":715112200,
      "sha1Hash":"d18dd27f4814e0898df98e7aa47cc08c477dfabc",
      "md5Hash":"ded916cf74e7dd97e698285c2880e7a8",
      "repositories":[
         {
            "repositoryId":"foobar",
            "repositoryName":"foobar",
            "path":"/master-5678.zip",
            "artifactUrl":"http://nexus.example.com/nexus/content/repositories/foobar/master-5678.zip",
            "canView":true
         }
      ],
      "canDelete":false
   }
}
```

Thanks to Rich @ sonatype support.

Comment: I searched the official documentation, did I miss anything or does the documentation not mention real world REST API examples ?

Comment: Its been a few years, but at the time the documentation was quite weak. (Hence the creation of this slack overflow issue)

Comment: did not work for me. Lots of package information are shown (size, last modified) but the checksum is missing